# How can I reset my HOST environment variable on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I tried to change some things in my Rails app to configure meta description but it did not work. It included changing my `HOST` environment variable on Heroku through the command `heroku config:set HOST=`. I deleted all my files and re-pushed on Heroku but I still get an "App crashed" error.
I get this message:

```
     ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.15.1 to 7.16.0
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.15.1 to 7.16.0
2018-09-18T06:48:01.668275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-09-18T06:48:02.705400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-09-18T06:48:02.848536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-09-18T06:48:02.720940+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2018-09-18T06:48:02.726712+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2018-09-18 06:48:02 +0000 ===
2018-09-18T06:48:02.726956+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2018-09-18T06:48:02.727461+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-09-18T06:56:31.089861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2018-09-18T06:56:31.090223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2018-09-18T06:56:40.477994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45736 -e production`
2018-09-18T06:56:54.441128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-18T06:56:55.580057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com request_id=fc981100-f310-4e0b-8842-3bc0c8f46188 fwd="84.14.51.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=http
2018-09-18T06:56:55.455001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com request_id=e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7 fwd="84.14.51.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=218ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237118+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237134+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.0 application starting in production
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237136+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237137+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237138+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237140+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237141+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237142+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:45736
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237143+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-09-18T06:56:55.237145+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] Started GET "/" for 84.14.51.130 at 2018-09-18 06:56:55 +0000
2018-09-18T06:56:55.287015+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] Processing by PagesController#search as HTML
2018-09-18T06:56:55.415134+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]   Adventure Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "adventures".* FROM "adventures" WHERE "adventures"."active" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["active", true], ["LIMIT", 4], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2018-09-18T06:56:55.445624+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]   Rendered pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application (22.7ms)
2018-09-18T06:56:55.445888+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 159ms (ActiveRecord: 29.2ms)
2018-09-18T06:56:55.422755+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]   Rendering pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-18T06:56:55.446911+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]
2018-09-18T06:56:55.446952+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `level_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x000055f99d153370>):
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447317+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     60:                                 <div class="form-group">
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447320+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     61:                                  <label></label>
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447321+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     62:
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447336+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     63:                         <%= f.select :level_eq, [["Débutant","Débutant"],
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447338+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     64:                         ["Intermédiaire","Intermédiaire"],
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447341+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     66:                           ["Expert","Expert"]],
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447345+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447339+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7]     65:                          ["Avancé","Avancé"],
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447374+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:63:in `block in _app_views_pages_search_html_erb__4235502768366703437_47265285208920'
2018-09-18T06:56:55.447376+00:00 app[web.1]: [e2277588-af4b-4d45-847d-628f074f8cd7] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_pages_search_html_erb__4235502768366703437_47265285208920'
2018-09-18T07:00:28.456109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com request_id=8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319 fwd="84.14.51.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
2018-09-18T07:00:28.426449+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] Started GET "/" for 84.14.51.130 at 2018-09-18 07:00:28 +0000
2018-09-18T07:00:28.438764+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]   Adventure Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  "adventures".* FROM "adventures" WHERE "adventures"."active" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["active", true], ["LIMIT", 4], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2018-09-18T07:00:28.440286+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]   Rendering pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-18T07:00:28.427876+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] Processing by PagesController#search as HTML
2018-09-18T07:00:28.451244+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]   Rendered pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application (10.8ms)
2018-09-18T07:00:28.452885+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]
2018-09-18T07:00:28.451496+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
2018-09-18T07:00:28.452928+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `level_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x000055f99d039958>):
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453270+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     60:                                 <div class="form-group">
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453276+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     63:                         <%= f.select :level_eq, [["Débutant","Débutant"],
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453272+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     61:                                  <label></label>
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453274+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     62:
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453278+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     65:                          ["Avancé","Avancé"],
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453277+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     64:                         ["Intermédiaire","Intermédiaire"],
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453364+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:63:in `block in _app_views_pages_search_html_erb__4235502768366703437_47265285208920'
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453279+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]     66:                           ["Expert","Expert"]],
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453318+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319]
2018-09-18T07:00:28.453366+00:00 app[web.1]: [8cf6df4b-aa41-4dcb-818a-281e2a663319] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_pages_search_html_erb__4235502768366703437_47265285208920'
2018-09-18T07:33:59.460148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2018-09-18T07:33:59.460627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-09-18T07:34:00.381819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-09-18T07:34:00.510580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-09-18T07:34:00.394804+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2018-09-18T07:34:00.401884+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2018-09-18 07:34:00 +0000 ===
2018-09-18T07:34:00.401892+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2018-09-18T07:34:00.401977+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-09-18T12:23:25.742652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2018-09-18T12:23:25.742987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2018-09-18T12:23:31.801361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45496 -e production`
2018-09-18T12:23:37.998863+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878204+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878239+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.0 application starting in production
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878241+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878247+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878248+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878254+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878255+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878256+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:45496
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878257+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-09-18T12:23:39.878265+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] Started GET "/" for 84.14.51.130 at 2018-09-18 12:23:39 +0000
2018-09-18T12:23:39.889960+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] Processing by PagesController#search as HTML
2018-09-18T12:23:39.958889+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]   Adventure Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "adventures".* FROM "adventures" WHERE "adventures"."active" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["active", true], ["LIMIT", 4], ["OFFSET", 0]]
2018-09-18T12:23:39.961971+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]   Rendering pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-09-18T12:23:39.968395+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]   Rendered pages/search.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
2018-09-18T12:23:39.968547+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 79ms (ActiveRecord: 22.1ms)
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969053+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969089+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `level_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00005565f5722cd8>):
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969246+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     60:                                 <div class="form-group">
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969254+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     61:                                  <label></label>
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969255+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     62:
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969256+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     63:                         <%= f.select :level_eq, [["Débutant","Débutant"],
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969257+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     64:                         ["Intermédiaire","Intermédiaire"],
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969258+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     65:                          ["Avancé","Avancé"],
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969259+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]     66:                           ["Expert","Expert"]],
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969262+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f]
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969289+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_pages_search_html_erb__3680868169337598520_46948179683480'
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969288+00:00 app[web.1]: [45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f] app/views/pages/search.html.erb:63:in `block in _app_views_pages_search_html_erb__3680868169337598520_46948179683480'
2018-09-18T12:23:39.969128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com request_id=45b9bc22-8bd8-4382-9eb0-aa2edd67927f fwd="84.14.51.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=94ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
2018-09-18T12:23:40.539688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com request_id=339652f4-0fd7-44d0-b91e-8f0064580354 fwd="84.14.51.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=http
```

I assume this comes from my command to change Heroku host. How do I reset the `HOST` environment variable on Heroku?

Comment: What are the error messages in your heroku console? (In console, run `heroku logs`)

Comment: Hello jvillian, thanks ! here is the message: heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers.herokuapp.com request_id=6d8b69e4-cf56-4d39-ae5e-fda8286e1d1e fwd="82.254.144.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï that's probably not it. there would be some other error as well. use `heroku logs --tail` to see last few errors.

Comment: i get this :heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=bourse-aux-aventuriers-2.herokuapp.com . I really do not know what it refers to...

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï, there's probably a lot more output. Can you [edit] your question and add it there? After you paste it, please select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: Hi chris, I did edit my question with the output but I do not know how to get to more info. Any recommandation ?

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï, that's not the part of the output that's relevant. It shows an [HTTP 302 (not modified)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) response. It's not an error. When you run `heroku logs` it should show a _whole bunch_ of output, not just one line. I'm asking to see all of it.

Comment: done, I copied the whole output. I understand that there is two problems : a reference to the database that is not recognized and a "host" problem. This is the latest I'm not able to understand ... thanks :)

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï, I don't see the host problem. It all looks like Rails / database issues to me (and I'm not a Rails developer, though I'm quite familiar with Heroku).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked, you can unset environment variables with [`heroku config:unset`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#remove-a-config-var), e.g.

```
heroku config:unset HOST
```

It is also possible to add, modify, and remove environment variables using Heroku's web interface.

This may not be the actual cause of your application crashing, though.